# Where to put websocket establishment code in React functional component

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I have a react app where I am establishing websocket connection with a server.
My issue is, I am not able to understand where to define the websocket connection.

**Approach 1:**

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { w3cwebsocket as W3CWebSocket } from "websocket";

const  websocketUrl = `ws://127.0.0.1:1234/ws${window.location.pathname}/`
const socket = new W3CWebSocket(websocketUrl);
        
function Page() {
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.onopen = () => {
            console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
        };

        socket.onclose = () => {
        console.log('WebSocket Closed!');
        };

        socket.onmessage = (message) => {
        ...
    }, []);
    ...
    }
export default Page;
```

> **Result:** This approach is not working because I am defining websocket outside the component, which is being invoked on load in
> main app as well.

**Approach 2:**
I moved websocket inside the component.

```
function Page() {
    const  websocketUrl = `ws://127.0.0.1:1234/ws${window.location.pathname}/`
    const socket = new W3CWebSocket(websocketUrl);
    useEffect(() => {
    ...
```

> Result: This resulted in multiple websocket connections. Whenever any
> state changes, it establishes a new connection.

**Approach 3:**
I have moved the websocket connection inside the `useEffect()`

```
function Page() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const  websocketUrl = `ws://127.0.0.1:1234/ws${window.location.pathname}/`
        const socket = new W3CWebSocket(websocketUrl);
        
        socket.onopen = () => {
            console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
        };
        .....
```

> Result: I was getting error when I tried to use `socket` outside
> `useEffect()`.

What would be the solution here? How to properly put websocket establishment?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach 3 looks to be the closest working solution. I think the tweak you need is to declare `socket` in component scope. Here you may need to check the socket is defined if referencing anywhere in the component as it will still be null on the initial render.

Other key pieces are the effect hook's dependency array. If you want the effect to run only once when the component mounts then use an empty dependency array. Don't forget to also return an effect cleanup function to close any open sockets and reset the `socket` to null in this component.

```
let socket = null;

function Page() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const  websocketUrl = `ws://127.0.0.1:1234/ws${window.location.pathname}/`;
    socket = new W3CWebSocket(websocketUrl);
        
    socket.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    };
    .....

    // effect cleanup function
    return () => {
      // any socket closure logic, cleanup etc..
      socket = null;
    };
  }, []); // <-- empty dependency array
```